# Не работает JS в Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

Здравствуйте. Не могу разобраться, почему в firefox не работает, помогите, пожалста

```js
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
  'total': t,
  'days': days,
  'hours': hours,
  'minutes': minutes,
  'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
  var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

  daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
  hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
  minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
  secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

  if (t.total <= 0) {
    clearInterval(timeinterval);
  }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline = '2017-11-12 20:00:00 GMT+04:00';

initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

```html
<div id='clockdiv'>
  <span class='days'></span>
  <span class='hours'></span>
  <span class='minutes'></span>
  <span class='seconds'></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Проблема в формате даты.
В Firefox `new Date('2017-11-12 20:00:00 GMT+04:00')` - это `Invalid date`, а в Chrome это `Sun Nov 12 2017 19:00:00 GMT+0300 (MSK)`

Вам нужно привести строку с датой к перевариваемему обоими браузерами виду

```js
console.log(
Date.parse('2017-11-12 20:00:00 GMT+04:00'),
Date.parse('2017-11-12 20:00:00 GMT+04:00'.replace(' GMT', ''))
)
```

Comment: спасибо, исправил